# Simple Networking; Threads issue

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I'm trying to make a simple client-server networking program. Initially, I was not running the  Server and Client objects concurrently. The command prompt would just get stuck on trying to run the program. I then decided to use `threads`. The result is the same; I believe I have to use `wait()` and `notify()` somewhere but I'm not able to get it.
The Server needs to run first, but it will have to wait for the `incoming Socket` reference before it can proceed. I believe some lines need to be shifted here and there before a `wait-and-notify` mechanism is implemented. Here's my code so far -:

```
package networking;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Server implements Runnable
{
        ServerSocket ss;
    Socket incoming;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ss = new ServerSocket(8189);
            incoming = ss.accept();
            OutputStream outs = incoming.getOutputStream();
            InputStream ins = incoming.getInputStream();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(ins);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outs);
            out.println("Hello, Bye to exit");
            out.println("This is the server program");
            out.println("It will echo client stuff");
            boolean done = false;
            while(!done && in.hasNextLine())
            {
                out.println("Echo: " + in.nextLine());
                if(in.nextLine().trim().equals("Bye"))
                    done = true;
            }
            incoming.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable
{
    Socket s;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 8189);
            InputStream ins = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outs = s.getOutputStream();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(ins);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outs);
            while(in.hasNextLine())
                System.out.println("Client: " + in.nextLine());
            out.println("Bye");
            s.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class Networking
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Thread server = new Thread(new Server());
        Thread client = new Thread(new Client());
        server.start();
        client.start();
    }
}
```

Any tips and pointers would be much appreciated; I just need a nod(or more) in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for opening serve and client is correct. But the problem is in the while loop for reading or writing data it falls in a deadlock. Because after establishing the connection booth server and client is waiting for each other to write something in the stream. Try with this.

```
class Server implements Runnable {

    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket incoming;

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server STarted");
            ss = new ServerSocket(8189);
            incoming = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            OutputStream outs = incoming.getOutputStream();
            InputStream ins = incoming.getInputStream();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(ins);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outs);
            out.println("Hello, Bye to exit");
            out.println("This is the server program");
            out.println("It will echo client stuff");
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) { // && in.hasNextLine()
//              out.println("Echo: " + in.nextLine());
//              if (in.nextLine().trim().equals("Bye")) {
//                  done = true;
//              }
                out.println("TEsting from server");
            }
            incoming.close();
            System.out.println("End server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```